# Why do we need dynamic branch to render multiple light sources

Tags: directx, rendering, shader

I was reading Real-Time Rendering (Third Edition). In Section 7.9 Combining Lights and Materials, it says that "If dynamic branches are not used, then a different shader needs to be generated for each possible combination of lights and material type".

I think static branch is well suited for this problem. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your 'engine' code is determining which sorts of lights and materials are in your scene, and that is (usually) dynamic. To communicate this to your shader, you would need to pass the information in some way - through uniforms, textures or buffers. That data is not static, and thus, any conditional expressions based on the information contained in them is dynamic branching.

Some graphics APIs/drivers do an optimization under-the-hood, and essentially recompile your shaders with multiple branches predicted, and call this 'static branching'. For example, the shader documentation for [D3D9](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb944006(VS.85).aspx?tduid=(3ce0c70a4b2f7b28e79c4c8e27b374ce)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-oqdpBjsyTR0HGkhXj0r_Uw)()#Flow_Control&ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-oqdpBjsyTR0HGkhXj0r_Uw), it states that:

> Static branching allows blocks of shader code to be switched on or off
>   based on a Boolean shader constant.

In other APIs such as OpenGL, it's not well advertised exactly when these sort of optimizations occur, although presumably they do happen. It also may (will) be different from driver to driver. However, it's far more reliable to write the combinations yourself, this way you know what type of branching is being used (none!).

If your scene has unchanging lights and materials, then you could "hardcode" the light and material types in your shader (say as constants). However, this is essentially what the quote is saying - you can use static branches, but a different shader needs to be generated for every combination of lights and materials.

Comment: But at the end of Section 3.2 The Programmable Shader Stage of this book, it says that branches based on the values of uniforms are actually static branches. I think this kind of branch is different from branches based on the values of dynamic source such as texture data.

Comment: I guess you could argue that if you use static branches, then the driver may well generate a different shader for every combination under the hood anyway, so the quote may still be correct.

Comment: updated my answer with a bit about static branching optimizations.

Comment: @Columbo Different shaders based on bool in constant buffers are unlikely since dx11 hardware, GPU branches are almost free as long as wave lanes all follow the same path. It is even enforced in DX12 has it is by design that the compilation happen at CreatePipeline and nowhere else.